# Word for making a tentative meeting non-tentative (meaning it will definitely go ahead)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for removing the provisional or tentative property of something, in particular meetings.

I would like to use this in the context where I set up a provisional meeting and anyone from a group can make it "definite" and the meeting is going ahead.

Is there a word to describe that action or the outcome (even saying a meeting becomes "definite" does not sound right)? Ideally it would be a word that can be used in a professional context, i.e. most people would know what I mean if I use that word.

An example sentence could be:

"I have set up a tentative meeting for 2pm. It can be `???` by anyone present if the situation deteriorates."

or perhaps

"I have set up a tentative meeting for 2pm. Anyone present can declare it `???` if the situation deteriorates."

Comment: I was thinking of confirm, but it sounds like it could easily be misunderstood for confirming the tentative nature of the meeting. I.e. confirming is (at least for me) associated with reporting a current status, not to change it.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence into which the word would fit.

Comment: Anyone from the group can confirm it? "Let's [**roll (2.10)**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roll) with that meeting."

Comment: I edited the question by providing two example sentences.

Comment: Following the question edit **confirmed** is quite clear for the first `???` For the second `???` perhaps **definite**.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **made definite** in your first example and **definite** in your second.

> "I have set up a tentative meeting for 2pm. It can be **made definite** by anyone present if the situation deteriorates."

> "I have set up a tentative meeting for 2pm. Anyone present can declare it **definite** if the situation deteriorates."

I have often encountered these words in a professional context. There is no better antonym for *tentative* than **definite** when it comes to meetings.